# OpenStack Projects List HTTP request ignoring pagination "limit=" parameter

Tags: java, http, openstack

I am trying to retrieve a list of projects from the OpenStack API, and would like to use pagination in order to retrieve n projects at a time.

In the OpenStack documentation, it states that I can append "/?limit=n" to the URL and up to n results will be fetched accordingly.

However, when executing the GET request to the URL as follows:
https://identity-3.eu-de-1.cloud.sap/v3/auth/projects/?limit=1

I still get ALL projects. I can't seem to understand what I am missing.

NOTE: the request itself works and returns results as needed, but simply ignores the limit parameter (this is not an authentication issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it does not all OpenStack API provide **limit** parameter

In keystone API doc, there is no **limit** parameter in Request parameter descriptions for /v3/auth/projects API
[keystone-project-API-doc](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=get-available-project-scopes-detail,list-projects-detail#get-available-project-scopes)

Other services like cinder volume list, it provides limit parameter in doc
[cinder-volume-API-doc](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/block-storage/v3/index.html?expanded=list-accessible-volumes-detail)